# TCP Proxy SSL/HTTPS using Java

Tags: java, https, tcp, proxy

I am trying to create my very own proxy with Java. I am not the best with this kind of networking stuff, so please consider that when I look dumb.

Well anyway to describe my problem: I am running a simple java `Socket-Server`, and registered it as a proxy in Firefox. The proxy itself works with HTTP-Server with no problem. If I try a HTTPS server, Firefox gives me the following Error: 
`"SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"`
I know that `SSL/TSL` is the protocol used to decode and encode the transported data. What irritates me here is that if I try to read the byte-Array, which I receive as an answer, as an String it shows me the decoded HTML Code.

Click here to view the code: https://hastebin.com/muyusalopu.java

Can someone explain to me what the exact problem is and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> What irritates me here is that if I try to read the byte-Array, which
>   I recieve as an answer, as an String it shows me the decoded HTML
>   Code.

this is the definition of the constuctor of the String class that you are using

**String**(byte[] bytes)

Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset.

> why there is no encryption ?

Because you are using urlConnection if you want to have encryption then you should use httpsUrlConnection class

Comment: What I mean is that the data I recieve from an https website can be read without any extra decryption

Comment: Ok thank you for that :) but the main problem stayed :(

Comment: Using `URL.openConnection()` on an https: URL (automatically) uses `HttpsURLConnection` which is a subclass of (and thus assignable to) `URLConnection`. To be exact currently it uses `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl` which is a subclass of `HttpsURLConnection` but that is undocumented and may change.